# sheetrock js callback function

Tags: javascript, callback, sheetrock

How to use callback option in sheetrock.js? I'm trying to get the output from the sheetrock as a variable to be used as input for another function, but having difficulty due to my limited JS knowledge. Any help please?

```
    var d = new Date();
var month = new Array();
month[0] = "Jan";
month[1] = "Feb";
month[2] = "Mar";
month[3] = "Apr";
month[4] = "May";
month[5] = "Jun";
month[6] = "Jul";
month[7] = "Aug";
month[8] = "Sep";
month[9] = "Oct";
month[10] = "Nov";
month[11] = "Dec";
var n = month[d.getMonth()];
var y = d.getFullYear();
$("#value").sheetrock({
  url: 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XSVP75fJkq34gLHhwIsEWOC3My-6xnbVURk4U_wotD0/edit#gid=0',
  query: "select C where B = "+ y +" and A = '"+ n +"'",
  callback: draw
});

function draw(data, sheetrock,response) {

   console.log(); // how to get the output from sheetrock as a variable?

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how sheetrock callback works :

```
function draw(error, options, response) {
  if (error) {
    console.log('fail');
  }
  else{
    console.log(response.html);
  }
}
```

**EDIT :** To put it into a global variable :

```
var globalVar = {};
function draw(data, sheetrock,response) {
    globalVar.response = response.html;
}
function use(){
    $('#test').html(globalVar.response);
}
```

**Full working example :** https://codepen.io/andreds/pen/baomVq

Comment: Thanks for ur response. But, the problem is I dont have much expertise in JS. Can you show how to get the output from the console.log into a variable (to be used outside the function, later)?
Besides, I'm getting "undefined" in the console and not the intended value.

Comment: oh, you want to put it in a global var ? You can use :  window.yourGlobalVariable = response.data;

Comment: Sorry Andre, but I'm still getting "undefined" in the console. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you try to do : console.log(response) and give me the output ?

Comment: here is the response:

e {request: e, options: e, raw: {…}, attributes: {…}, rows: Array(2), …}
attributes
:
{last: 1, rowNumberOffset: 0, labels: Array(1)}
html
:
"<tr><td>26.68</td></tr>"
options
:
e {user: {…}, request: {…}, requestIndex: "1XSVP75fJkq34gLHhwIsEWOC3My-6xnbVURk4U_wotD0_0_select C where B = 2018 and A = 'Jan'"}
raw
:
{version: "0.6", reqId: "0", status: "ok", sig: "601120954", table: {…}}
request
:
e {options: e, index: "1XSVP75fJkq34gLHhwIsEWOC3My-6xnbVURk4U_wotD0_0_select C where B = 2018 and A = 'Jan'"}
rows
:
(2) [e, e]
__proto__
:
Object

Comment: Ok, so you have to use "response.html", here is a full working example : http://jsfiddle.net/j5hmoL0e/1/ (click run)

Comment: Thanks for ur effort Silva, but I have managed to pass the result to html already. The problem I have is to store the output to a variable (that can be used again in another JS function)... to be more precise, I intend to use this output as value for Gauge.js

Comment: Can you please check my new code pen : https://codepen.io/andreds/pen/baomVq

you can use global variables (like in my example) to use your var in another place of your javascript code (into Gauge.js if you want).

Comment: Dear Silva,
Thanks again. Sorry, if I was not clear in the beginning itself. But, the crux of my problem lies in being able to pass my output from Sheetrock as a variable for use in another JS function. Not to be passed to html (this I have already achieved).

Comment: Right, so please give me the full code, and comment where you want to place pour variable

Comment: Attached is the fiddle. Thanks in advance.

https://jsfiddle.net/mpremkumar/j0r6691g/

Comment: Just create your gauge at the callback :) Here it is : https://jsfiddle.net/j0r6691g/1/ 

If it's ok, please don't forget to mark my answered as the solution.

Comment: Man, seriously... That's it? I was breaking my head for about a week (of course I'm new to JS). 
My heartfelt thanks dude.!

Comment: My pleasure, have a nice day :)

Comment: Hey Silva, just as a follow up qtn. What if I need to have multiple charts in the same html page that are generated thro multiple queries? how to access the variable in that case?

Comment: use the same sheetrock function with a large query, that return X results. foreach result, create a graph :) (use loop)