# Cannot get HTML value of a <p>

Tags: javascript

So there is following HTML code:

```
<div id="hr">
      <script id="item-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
        <div class="card_wrapper col-md-4 col-sm-12">
          <div class="item_card">
            <div class="restaurant_name">
            <p>Empfang restaurant: <span class="decorated">{{cellsArray.[0]}}</span></p>
            </div>
            <div class="updated">
              Updated at: {{cellsArray.[1]}}
            </div>
            <div class="places_number">
            <p class="getme"> <span data-foo="0" class="places_number_from_google decorated">{{cellsArray.[2]}}</span> Places.</p>
            </div>
            <div style="background-color: red" class="places_number">
              <p> <span class="places_number_js"></span> Places.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="discount">
            <p><span class="decorated">{{cellsArray.[3]}} %</span> your Discount</p>
            </div>
            <div class="time">
              <p>Discount valid from <span class="decorated">{{cellsArray.[4]}}</span> till <span class="decorated">{{cellsArray.[5]}}</span> </p>
            </div>
            <div id="button" class="button" onclick="displayDiv()">
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Details</button>
            </div>
          </div>
          </div>
    </script>
    </div>
```

It takes some js values from Handelbars.js library. Everything is displayed in a perfect way.
Than, what I wanna do is to get values of a p tag. To do so there is some js code:

```
var mySpreadsheet = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rz5ZHlJgbrAGDDXIMlwQRWPTdb57D1vV3EKHoWn_tR0/edit#gid=0';
// handlebars
var HRTemplate = Handlebars.compile($('#item-template').html());

$('#hr').sheetrock({
  url: mySpreadsheet,
  rowTemplate: HRTemplate
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log("ready");
  var target = document.getElementsByClassName("getme");
  console.log(target);
  for (var k = 0; k < target.length; k++){
    console.log(target[k].innerHTML)
  }
});
```

This says to console that there is a HTML collection of length 0 which is strange. But if I execute same code in browsers console everythings works perfect. The output than is as follows:

```
HTMLCollection(4) [ p.getme, p.getme, p.getme, p.getme
 ]
```

​

Where do I face a mistake?

Comment: You are reading it before the items are rendered to the page. Does whatever template tell you when it is done loading?

Comment: @epascarello how come I'm reading it after if I put my code in `$(document).ready(function() {`   What might be the solution for this?
According to docs there is no way to track when items are rendered

Comment: document.ready has no clue about templating.

Comment: @epascarello how can I solve this issue than?

Comment: So where are you initializing the template?

Comment: @epascarello just updated the js part if the question

Comment: No clue what sheetrock is, but if that is what is rendering it, than you need to see if it has an event to tell you when it is done creating the elements. Does it have some sort of callback or load event?

Comment: @epascarello [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48110766/sheetrock-js-callback-function] kind of here?

Comment: `$('#hr').sheetrock({
  url: mySpreadsheet,
  rowTemplate: HRTemplate,
  callback: loaded
});

function loaded(){
  var target = document.getElementsByClassName("getme");
  console.log(target);
  for (var k = 0; k < target.length; k++){
    console.log(target[k].innerHTML)
  }
}`

@epascarello the thing I need. Huge thanks for your input!!!

Answer (score -1):

You are reading the class it self
try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log("ready");
  var target = document.getElementsByClassName("getme");
  console.log(target);
  for (var k = 0; k < target.length; k++){
    console.log(target[k][0].innerHTML)
  }
});
```

Comment: It's not the classname since I'm using .innerHTML after . Didn't got your point...